# Get Option Value of changed Select

Tags: jquery

All,
I have multiple selects on my page all with the same class. The class is called event_selection. Whenever someone changes one of these selects I'd like to get the selected option value with jQuery.

How can I go about doing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.event_selection').on('change', function() { // bind change event
  // get the value
  alert( this.value );  // or $(this).val(), but previous one is faster
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.event_selection').change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

This thread is possibly a duplicate of 500 others though...